Powershell getting list from large directories fast
I spent weeks trying to figure out the best way to use Get-Childitem or LS or DIR to generate the file listing of some VERY large directories (> 1M files per directory) on remote servers (servers.txt) when I came across the idea of using .NET.
The core of the script below is found in many places on this website and the web in general. It is so much faster than get-childitem.
I am not familiar with .NET commands. Is there a way I can modify this such that it will also return the file size and date/time modified?
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content servers.txt) -ScriptBlock {
    $directoryPath = 's:\some\path\structure'
    ##### gets directory listing #####
    Try {
        $Folders = [System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles($directoryPath, '*.*', 'AllDirectories')
    }
    catch {
        $_.Exception.message
    }
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines('c:\temp\outfile.txt', $folders)
}


Hey, would you please accept my answer if it solved your problem?

Sure there is, the static method Directory.EnumerateFiles only returns the file's absolute path (.FullName) however if you need more information about the files you can change the logic to use the instance method EnumerateFiles from DirectoryInfo which returns an enumerable of FileInfo. Worth noting here that since this method outputs objects instead of simple strings, the way you export to a file should also be different, you should use a cmdlet capable of converting objects into structured data, for example Csv (Export-Csv) or Json (ConvertTo-Json):
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content servers.txt) -ScriptBlock {
    try {
        $directoryPath = Get-Item 's:\some\path\structure'
        $directoryPath.EnumerateFiles('*', 'AllDirectories') |
            Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime, Length | # can select more properties here
            Export-Csv 'c:\temp\outfile.csv' -NoTypeInformation
    }
    catch {
        $_.Exception.Message
    }
}

Another notable mention is that this method will stop the enumeration as soon as there is an inaccessible file or folder, in which case you need to change the logic of your code to handle that.
Here is how the code would look:
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content servers.txt) -ScriptBlock {
    & {
        $enumerator = (Get-Item 's:\some\path\structure').
            EnumerateFiles('*', 'AllDirectories').
            GetEnumerator()

        while ($true) {
            try {
                if (-not $enumerator.MoveNext()) {
                    # done enumeration, break the loop
                    break
                }
                # else, output
                $enumerator.Current
            }
            catch {
                # you can leave this block empty to ignore any error,
                # or have error handling needed if you need loging, etc
            }
        }
    } |
        Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime, Length | # can select more properties here
        Export-Csv 'c:\temp\outfile.csv' -NoTypeInformation
}


Based on comments, the snippets are too slow. Here is another version of the first one using a StreamWriter to write to a file and manually constructs the Csv instead.
Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Get-Content servers.txt) -ScriptBlock {
    try {
        $writer = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new('c:\temp\outfile.csv')
        $writer.WriteLine('"FullName","LastWriteTime","Length"')
        $directoryPath = Get-Item 's:\some\path\structure'

        foreach ($file in $directoryPath.EnumerateFiles('*', 'AllDirectories')) {
            $writer.WriteLine([string]::Format(
                '"{0}","{1}","{2}"',
                $file.FullName,
                $file.LastWriteTime,
                $file.Length))
        }
    }
    catch {
        $_.Exception.Message
    }
    finally {
        if ($writer) {
            $writer.Dispose()
        }
    }
}


Thank you @santiago squarzon for your prompt reply and help. I like your script however, you've fallen back to using Get-Item instead of the .net cmds I have in the original script which makes it SOOO much slower.  The code snippet I used above gave the directory listing of  3,081,589 lines in under 3 minutes.  Using Get-item and it's been running for an hour.
Speed is of the essence here.

$file = New-Object System.IO.Fileinfo($filePath)
$fileSize = $file.Length
$fileSize```

I like the potential with this.  I

t's these "system.io..." commands I'm not getting. I've tried reading the MS articles and it's greek to me. I just know this works so much faster than Get-Childitem or Dir or any other windows cmd I've found so I want to continue using this for this one task. 

Thank you @Santiago for posting so quickly and I appreciate the input but it's just too slow. I'm open to suggestions

@dbutts you won't get something much faster than this, creating a DirectoryInfo instance instead of using Get-Item will not make this any faster

Thanks @Santiago. By comparison, the script i listed above took 3 minutes to write 3M lines of output, but the one with Get-Item took over 13 hours. I just wish I could get file sizes from the script I originally posted.

@dbutts i can post another version that doesnt use Export-Csv but how do you need to display the file's Length in a plain text file?

i'd prefer comma separated, or at least delimited in some way so that i can import the file path, file name & file size into a db.  And thanks. I can do all of this in PS so many ways, and get file name, path, size, dttm modified, et. al. but it's so very slow. Once I stumbled across the .net stuff and realized how much faster it was I've been determined to make it work.

@dbutts have you tried removing the Select-Object and Export-Csv to see how long it takes without that?

i have not but I'll try that tomorrow

which snippet did you try @dbutts the first or second? i'll add a version that doesn't need Export-Csv doubt it will make it much faster tho

i used the one with export-csv

@dbutts see the updated answer. it won't get faster than that.

Jackpot!  1 minute, 13 secs, 3,081,590 lines with full path, dttm and size! Genius!

@dbutts surprising that Export-Csv is making things so slow, I guess in powershell 5.1 it was very poorly optimized but glad it helped

@dbutts I think I know why it was taking so much before. I was missing a | after Select-Object FullName, LastWriteTime, Length. Apologies. It was all going back to local session so that is probably what was taking so much

I might give the original version a shot again, with |select-object  but so far this is working fine the way it is!
